# C# didisoft pgp decrypting to its original file type

Tags: c#, windows, file-extension, file-type

i am using DiDiSoft Library to encrypt and decrypt my files.

Apparently, encryption and decryption goes on smoothly but when the files are decrypted from .pgp extension, i have to manually rename the file to its original extension. Below are the original codes from the didisoft website:

```
using System;
using DidiSoft.Pgp;

public class DecryptDemo
{
 public void Demo()
 {
  // initialize the library
  PGPLib pgp = new PGPLib();

  string inputFileLocation = @"c:\INPUT.pgp";
  string privateKeyLocation = @"c:\private_key.asc";
  string privateKeyPassword = "key password";
  string outputFile = @"c:\Output.txt";

  // decrypt and obtain the original file name
  // of the decrypted file
  string originalFileName =
              pgp.DecryptFile(inputFileLocation,
                          privateKeyLocation,
                          privateKeyPassword,
                          outputFile);
 }
}
```

I am using a windows system and i know that there is this features like in linux that can scan what filetype a file is in the command prompt(cmd). The windows will automatically have a text file(FileSign.txt) that has the signature of the files it knows.

How do i use the FileSign.txt and my visual C# program to scan and return a string of the extension and add it to the back of the `string outputFile = @"c:\Output.txt";` instead of always being a text file.

Answer (score 1):

The example above from the DidiSoft API expects that you have an up front agreement with your partners what type of OpenPGP files will be exchanged.

For example common naming of encrypted files (when only one file is in the OpenPGP archive) is *original file name with extension***.pgp**. Afterwards when it is decrypted either with [DidiSoft OpenPGP Library for .NET](http://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/) or by other OpenPGP software (GnuPG, Symantec, etc.) the output file is *original file name with extension* only. You can achieve this behavior with code like:

```
string outputFile = 
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFileLocation),
                 Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFileLocation);
```

On the other hand if you don't know in advance what type of file(s) will be in the expected archives, you can utilize the provided by DidiSoft methods to inspect the contents of an OpenPGP archive before actually decrypting it.

A complete example is available here http://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/examples/analyzing-unknown-openpgp-archives/#ListArchive

Answer (score 0):

I am actually looking for things like this:

EncryptedFile.pgp ----decryption---> DecryptedFile(no extension) ----use some checking methods----> DecryptedFile.extension

In windows, when u use command prompt to check files, "filetype Test.txt" it will check the first 20th byte to determine the file extension/type. It will also create a FileSign.txt file somewhere(maybe desktop or c drive) and the text files contains signature like these:

```
0001000000120100000400204C54534891908748, TTF, "True Type Font";
49443303,MP3,"Compressed Sound";
5249464610C810,AVI,"Audio Video Interleave (AVI) File";
524946462A38000057415645666D74,WAV,"Wave Audio File";
818102000200070104,AVB,"MS Chat Character";
81810300020007010400,BGB,"MS Chat Background File";
3B2068656C702E687066,HPF,"HP LaserJet Fonts";
4C44425800010100000000200000,LDB,"Internet Log File (Zone Alarm)";
5456444227,LOG,"Zone Alarm Data File";
9901A2043C,PKR,"PGP Public Key-ring File";
3C68746D6C3E0D0A3C62,PLG,"MS Developer Build Log";
9501CF0436,SKR,"PGP Secret Key-ring File";
74576263000000000000,SYD,"QEMM / Sysedit Backup File";
535A4444,??_,"MS Compress 5 File(?? Could be anything)";
4B57414A,??_,"MS Compress 6 File(?? Could be anything)";
60EA,ARJ,"ARJ Archive File";
424147,BAG,"BAG Archive";
425A68,BZ,"Bzip Archive File";
4D534346,CAB,"Microsoft Cabinet File";
4D4D5320,CKIT,"Commodore Compressed File";
303730373037,CPIO,"CPIO Archive File";
4352555348,CRU,"CRUSH Archive File";
4841,HA,"HA Archive File";
91334846,HAP,"HAP Archive File";
28546869732066696C65,HQX,"Mac BinHex";
5F27A889,JAR,"Jar Archive File";
2D6C68352D,LHA,"LHA Compressed File";
4D415243,MARC,"MS Archive File";
4D48574B,MHK,"Broderbund Mohawk Archive Format";
4453,Q,"Quantum Archive";
526172211A0700CF9073,RAR,"RAR Compressed File";
EDABEEDB,RPM,"Redhat Linux Archive";
53495421,SIT,"Stuffit v1 Archive File";
53747566664974,SIT,"Stuffit v5 Archive File";
484C53515A,SQZ,"SQZ Archive File";
417070204E616D6509,STF,"ShrinkToFit Compressed Archive";
554641,UFA,"UFA Archive File";
7863722046696C65,XCR,"XCR Archive File";
504B0304140000000800,ZIP,"Winzip 8.1";
504B3030504B0304,ZIP,"WINZIP Compressed";
5A4F4F20,ZOO,"ZOO Compressed File";
2E736E64,AU,"SoundMachine Audio File";
49424B1A,IBK,"Soundblaster Instrument Bank";
4D503344415441,M3D,"MPEG Audio Datafile";
4D546864,MID,"Musical Instrument Digital Interface (MIDI) File";
2E7261FD,RAM,"Real Audio File";
2E524D46,RM,"Real Media File";
5354455645024880,SND,"AU Format Sound";
437265617469766520566F6963652046696C651A,VOC,"Creative Sound File";
3B0D0A3B,ASM,"Uncompiled Assembly Code";
0000000C000000,ATN,"Adobe Photoshop Script";
406563686F206F66660D,BTM,"NDOS Batch to Memory";
23212F62696E2F73680A,CGI,"Common Gateway Interface Script";
2F2A202A202A202A202A,H,"C++ Header File";
484FF3C976332E39392E,OBS,"ObjectScript";
56435043483000000000,PCH,"MS C++  Precompiled Header File";
00000100000001480000,RSC,"Compiled Resources";
DCFE,EFX,"eFax file format";
0363080A,DBF,"Database File";
000100005374616E6461,MDB,"Microsoft Access file";
4D4C42,MLB,"MyLittleBase Database File";
00000041424300000000,ABC,"Micrografx ABC Flowcharter";
5157205665722E20,ABD,"Quicken Data File";
30000004150505,ADX,"Lotus Approach ADX File";
252150532D41646F6265,AI,"Adobe Illustrator";
5B7665725D,AMI,"Lotus Ami Pro";
5008,APP,"Clarion File Format";
49545346030000006000,CHM,"Compiled HTML Help File";
464158434F5645,CPE,"MS Office Fax Cover";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 10 Office 2000 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Word 8.0 Office 97 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,DOC,"Generic MS Office File";
504B0304140000000000,DOC,"Star Writer 6.0";
31BE000000AB0000,DOC,"MS Word for DOS v6 File";
1234567890FF,DOC,"MS Word 6.0 File";
7FFE340A,DOC,"MS Word File";
4D47582069747064,DS4,"Micrografix Designer 4";
4D5600FF0C0010000000,DST,"Micrografx Designer Template";
3C21454E54495459,DTD,"Xml DTD";
C5D0D3C6,EPS,"Adobe Encapsulated PostScript File";
00001A0007800100,FM3,"Lotus 123 v3 FMT File";
2000680020,FMT,"Lotus 123 v4 FMT File";
3C68746D6C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 1 File";
3C48544D4C3E,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 2 File";
3C21444F4354,HTM,"HyperText Markup Language 3 File";
000100004D534953414D204461746162617365,MNY,"Microsoft Money File";
1A0000030000,NSF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
1A000003000011000100,NTF,"Lotus Notes Data File";
255044462D312E320D0A25E2E3CF,PDF,"PDF-1.2";
AC9EBD8F,QDF,"Quicken Data File";
5157205665722E20,QSD,"Quicken Data File";
7B5C727466,RTF,"Rich Text Format";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1000000000000,SDW,"Star Writer 3 - 5";
C354565362BD8AFF0000,TV4,"WordPerfect Insert Overflow - Doc 4";
2000604060,WK1,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
00001A0000100400,WK3,"Lotus 123 v3 Worksheet";
00001A0002100400,WK4,"Lotus 123 v5";
00001A001004,WKS,"Lotus MS Worksheet";
2000604060,WKS,"Lotus 123 v1 Worksheet";
FF575043,WP,"WordPerfect v5 or v6";
090808000005000433,XLB,"Microsoft Excel Workbook";
0904060000004000,XLM,"Microsoft Excel Macro";
0902060000001000B9045C00,XLS,"MS Excel v2";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 2 File";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE1,XLS,"Excel 8.0 Office 97 Type 1 File";
0904060000001000F6055C00,XLS,"MS Excel v4 File";
FFFE3C0052004F004F00540053005400550042,XML,"MS Excel Document";
3C3F786D6C,XML,"MS Excel XML Document";
3D02,3D2,"Stereo CAD-3D 2 File";
33444D46,3DMF,"3D Meta File";
2A2A544939322A2A0100586E5669,92I,"TI Bitmap";
414D4646,AMFF,"AMFF Image File";
4A47040E000000,ART,"AOL ART 1";
4A47030E000000,ART,"AOL ART 2";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Generic File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 1 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 2 File";
424D,BMP,"Bitmap Type 3 File";
BB010001C800C80001,BRK/301,"Brooktrout Fax";
737263646F6369643A,CALS,"CALS Raster Image";
07204D4D,CAM,"QV-10 Camera File";
20770002,CBD,"Vector Map Data Format";
45594553,CE2,"Computer Eyes File";
802A5FD700000800000004000000,CIN,"Kodac Cineon";
43616C6967617269,COB,"Caligari Truespace 2 File";
43505446494C45,CPT,"Corel Photopaint";
43414C414D5553435647,CVG,"Calamus";
3ADE68B1,DCX,"DCX Graphic File";
56697374612044454D2046696C65,DEM,"Vista Landscape Format";
424D36,DIB,"DIB Image File";
53445058,DPX,"Cineon Image File";
01FF02040302,DRW,"Micrographx Graphic";
41433130,DWG,"Autocad R13/R14 File";
65020102,ECW,"Enhanced Compressed Wavelet";
0100000058000000,EMF,"Enhanced Metafile Graphic";
D0CF11E0A1B11AE100,FPX,"FlashPix";
53494D504C4520203D,FTS,"Flexible Image Transport System";
47494638,GIF,"ALL Types";
4850485034382D451E2B,GRO,"HP-48/49 GROB";
6E636F6C73,HDR,"ArcoInfo Binary Image";
354B5035315D2A67727280838563,HRU,"HRU Image";
EB3C902A,IMG,"GEM Raster file";
656C6D6F,INFINI-D,"Infini-D Graphics File";
49574301,IWC,"WaveL Image";
803E445343494D,J6I,"Ricoh Camera Image File";
4A4946393961,JIF,"Jeff's Image Format";
0000000C6A5020200D0A870A,JP2,"JPEG-2000 JP2 Image";
FFD8FFE1,JPG,"Generic 1 JPG";
FFD8FFE0,JPG,"Generic 2 JPG";
FFD8FFE14ED84578696600004949,JPG,"Kodak";
4D4D002A,KDC,"Kodak Camera DC20/40/50";
36344C414E204944424C4F434B,L64,"64LAN Image File";
464F524D,LBM,"Interchange File";
49492A00080000000E0000010400,LDF,"LuraDocument Format";
575602004745000E,LWF,"LuraWave Format";
3700001042000010000000003964,MBM,"Psion Series 5 Bitmap";
4D474C,MGL,"MosASCII Graphics Library File";
7B0A202043726561746564,MIF,"Image Magick File";
8A4D4E470D0A1A0A,MNG,"Multiple Image Format";
4D5046,MPW,"MosASCII Project Workspace File";
44616E4D,MSP,"Windows Paint File";
433634,N64,"64NET Image File";
6E6E0A005E00,NCR,"NCR G4";
6E6666,NFF,"WorldToolKit Neutral File Format";
4E4747000100,NGG,"Nokia Group Graphics";
4E4C4D20010200,NLM,"Nokia Logo File";
4E4F4C00010006010300,NOL,"Nokia Operator Logo";
4148,PAL,"Dr. Halo Palette File";
0000002000000001,PAT,"Gimp Pattern";
504158,PAX,"Secure Image File";
50340A,PBM,"Portable Bitmap";
6352010138093D00,PCD,"Kodak PhotoCD";
1B451B266C304F1B266C30451B26,PCL,"Page Control Language";
0A050108,PCX,"PC Paintbrush";
5032,PGM,"Portable Greymap File";
50350A,PGM,"Portable Greyscale";
5380F6344020,PIC,"Softimage";
504943DC30300100,PIC,"Psion Series 3 Bitmap";
9119,PIC,"PIC File";
50495820,PIX,"PABX Background";
89504E470D0A1A0A,PNG,"Portable Network Graphic";
889A0D12,PNG,"Portable Network Graphics File";
504F4C20466F726D6174,POL,"Polygon Model File";
5033,PPM,"Portable Pixmap File";
38425053000100000000,PSD,"Adobe PhotoShop";
7E424B00,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
5061696E742053686F702050726F20496D6167652046696C65,PSP,"Paint Shop Pro File";
514C4949464158,QFX,"Fax Image File";
6D6F6F76,QTM,"Apple Quick Time File";
464F524D41543D,RAD,"Radiance";
59A66A95,RAS,"SUN Raster File";
01DA01010003,RGB,"Silicon Graphics RGB";
52495833,RIX,"ColoRIX File";
23202449643A20,SID,"Seamless Image Graphic File";
4175746F43414420536C696465,SLD,"Slide Library File";
53746F726D3344,SOD,"Storm 3D Object Definition";
49492A00,TIFF,"TIFF Image File";
4D4D2A,TIF,"TIF Image File (Motorola)";
FADEBABE0101,WIC,"J Wavelet Image Codec";
D323000003000000,WLM,"CompW Image";
D7CDC69A,WMF,"Windows graphics metafile";
FF57504310,WPG,"WordPerfect Graphic";
2356524D4C2056322E30,WRL,"VRML Version 2 Image";
23646566696E65,XBM,"XBM - X11 Bitmap";
2F2A2058504D202A2F,XPM,"XPM - X11 Pixmap";
436C69656E742055726C43616368,DAT,"IE History DAT File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE Cache Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 IE History Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"98 & XP IE History Root Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Hist Subfolder Index dat ver 2 File";
55524C20020000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
55524C20030000,DAT,"XP IE Cache Index dat ver 1 File";
5B50686F6E655D,DUN,"Dial-Up Network Export File";
CFAD12FEC5FD,DBX,"Outlook Express Email Storage File";
3C21646F63747970652068746D6C207075626C6963,DCI,"AOL Web Email";
52657475726E2D506174683A203C,EML,"Outlook Express Email Message";
46726F6D202D20,EML,"Netscape Email Message";
46726F6D203F3F3F403F3F3F20,EML,"Eudora Email Message";
46726F6D3A20,EML,"Generic Email Message";
2142444E,PST,"Outlook 97 File";
0006156100000002000004D20000,HST,"Netscape HST";
574542,IGY,"Web Query";
5745420D0A310D0A687474703A2F,IQY,"Microsoft Web Query";
5F434153455F,CAS,"EnCase Case (or Backup) File";
FEEF01,GHO,"Norton Ghost Image File";
43363453207461706520696D6167652066696C65,T64,"C64 Tape Image";
43363420434152545249444745,CRT,"C64 Emul Cartridge File";
BABEEBEA,ANI,"NEOchrome Animation File";
4C504620,ANM,"DeluxePaint Animation";
3026B2758E66CF11A6D900AA0062,ASF,"Windows Media (ASF Compression)";
56445649,AVS,"Intel Digital Video Interface File";
44564D,DVM,"DVM Movie File";
52414E44,Filmstrip,"Adobe Filmstrip File Format";
AF12,FLC,"Animator Pro Flic Files";
494D4443,IC3,"Atari Image Film";
4C5A414E494D,LZA,"Lempel-Ziv-Oberhumer Compressed Animation";
07010100436F70797269,MMM,"Microsoft Media Clip";
000007B56D6F6F76,MOV,"QuickTime Movie File";
6D646174,QT,"Quick Time Movie File";
000001B3,MPEG,"MPEG Video File";
5E405C6E534D4A504547,SMJPEG,"Simple Animation File";
B5A2B0B3B3B0A2B5,CAL,"Windows 3.1 Calendar";
52545353,CAP,"Windows NT Netmon Capture File";
4D53434600000000,CDM,"Windows Update File";
50C30100080028,CLP,"Windows Clipboard File";
43524547,DAT,"Windows 95 Registry Files";
5348434333,DAT,"Windows 3.1 Registry File (REG.DAT)";
202020202020696E7465,FON,"Font File";
3F5F0300,GID,"General Index";
504D4343,GRP,"MS Windows Group";
3F5F0300,HLP,"Windows Help File";
4C4E0200,HLP,"Windows Help File";
48797065725465726D69,HT,"HyperTerminal File";
5B4578745368656C6C466F6C6465,INI,"Desktop.ini Folder Setting File";
47040100,JOB,"Scheduled Tasks File";
7B0D0A6F206331,LGC,"Application Log File";
4C00000001140200,LNK,"Windows Shortcut File";
4C5441520001,LTR,"Letter File";
2A5050442D41646F6265,PPD,"Postscript Printer Description File";
E3828596010000,PWL,"Windows Password File";
5245474544495434,REG,"Windows NT Registry File";
0D0A5B536865,SCF,"Shell Command File";
3B0D0A3B205468697320697320,SCP,"Dial-Up Network Script";
6749000078,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
4B490000,SHD,"Printer Spool File";
5245474544495434,SUD,"Registry Undo Files";
FF4B455942202020,SYS,"Keyboard driver file";
4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF,EXE,"Acrobat plugin, Executable, Screen Saver";
504B030414000600080000002100710E,XLSX,"MSExcel 2007 Document";
504B030414000600080000002100DDFC,DOCX,"MSWord 2007 Document";
7B5C72746631,RTF,"Rich Text File";
377ABCAF271C0003838E304BB97F,7z, "7z Compressed File";
FEFF,txt, "UTF-16 Big Endian text file";
FFFE,txt, "UTF-16 Little Endian text file";
EFBBBF,txt, "UTF-8 text file";
377ABCAF271C0003,7z, "7z Archive File";
504B03041400000800000FB6913D5EC6320C27,odt, "OpenOffice Document Text";
6162432C3132330D0A0000000000000000000000,CSV, "Comma Seperate Value File";
504B0304140,odp,"Open Office Presentation";
,,;
```

Is it possible to use this FileSign.txt to check and return the correct extension?

codes: blahblahblah

output(on a TextBox):

```
.exe
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately DidiSoft OpenPGP Library for .NET currently does not provide such functionality out of the box. The library assumes that you either have an upfront agreement with your partners what type of files will be exchanged or the original file name including extension is stored inside the .pgp archive. In your case you will have to first decrypt the file and afterwards try to determine its extension by probing with the mentioned FileSign.txt file.